# How to implement in-app purchase in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, in-app-purchase

currently I am new in windows phone 8.1 c# store application development .  my application need in-app purchase , I refer so many links on Internet I found documents on windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1 silverlight apps only , no specific document for windows phone 8.1 store application . as per windows phone 8 document I submit my application as beta app, and create one consumable product , for testing in currentAppsimulator class I have created one testwindoesphone.xml file and working fine but I dont know how to construct code with currentApp class. I have refer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn532254.aspx) ,  but every time I found 805a0194  error while I used CurrentApp class . please guide me for enalble in-app purchase in my windows phone 8.1 application .

```
async private void btnCurrentApp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LicenceInfo = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        //await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremimumVersion",false);

        if (LicenceInfo.ProductLicenses["PremimumVersion"].IsActive)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Already Purchased");
        }
        else
        {
           // await CurrentApp.RequestAppPurchaseAsync(false);
            //await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremimumVersion");
            await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremimumVersion");


            var productLicenses = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;


            MaybeGiveMeGold(productLicenses["Premimum App"], 0);
            //PurchaseResults purchaseResults = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync();
            //Debug.WriteLine("Purchase Status :: " + purchaseResults.Status);

        }

    }
```

please let me know that where to put appid or guid in appxmanifest file .

Note: I have already done store association for beta app.

Please help me out for that , sorry for poor English

Answer (score 2):

First you will call inside your purchase click button

```
await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("YourPurchase");
```

and inside it if its purchased you would execute inside

```
if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["YourPurchase"].IsActive)
{
}
```

Now you need to make sure that YourPurchase that you created inside your developer account online is running and it will be even shown inside your dashboard online along with your other published apps.

Comment: Thank You Jerin for reply , but i still get same error  . my question is how to test in-app purchase in beta app ? is there any way ? and please let me know where to put AppId or GUID which i found from developer account dashboard . please help me out for this .Thank You

Comment: You can use await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestAppPurchaseAsync("YourPurchase") for testing.Which would return true for all. Remember to comment it out and use the original one. You dont need app token now once you upload your app you will receive an option add in app product there you specify your product name remember it should be same as the one used in code and specify the price.

Comment: so if i want to use currentApp class then it is compulsory to publish my application ?

Comment: Yes Coz then only it would allow you to publish the in- app product

Comment: hey jerin it's work fine ..Thank You my product is durable so it is working fine . can you have any idea about consumable product how to manage them ?

Comment: Consumable product I havent used so cant guarantee on the correct steps to implement them.

Comment: If it did work then dont forget to mark it as answer to help others.